# How would i add the google search panel to my website with css, js and html?

Tags: javascript, html

Im currently working on my project NightScape which is a landing page for myself and others and i wanted to add a google search bar but all ive managed to do is make a text box which you can write in. Here is my original code, any ideas?

**HTML**

```html
<div class="nightsearch">
  <header>
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="nightsearchbox" placeholder="Search Google...">
  </header>
</div>
```

**JS**

```js
function search() {
var nightsearchbox = document.getElementById("nightsearchbox").value;
location.replace("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + nightsearchbox + "");
}
```

**CSS**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nightsearch {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 680px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 10vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05));
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
}

.nightsearchbox {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 30px;
  width: 400%;
  max-width: 660px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: left;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: left;
  text-align: left;
  min-height: 7vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may be you want. Just add a `search` button as well to make sure user `clicks` on it after `entering` the search words and then use `location.replace` to open up the google search page with you query words with an `onclick` function.

Also you do not have an `id` => `.nightsearchbox` its a `class` of your input. We can access this class using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method and then its value to pass it as query to `google` search page.

In addtion to make sure that search `icon` (button) stays next to the actual search input we need to wrap button `input` and `button` that in `div`

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
function search() {
  var nightsearchbox = document.querySelector(".nightsearchbox").value;
  location.replace("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + nightsearchbox + "");
}
```

```css
.nightsearch {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 10vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05));
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
}

.nightsearchbox {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 30px;
  max-width: 660px;
  text-align: left;
  min-height: 7vh;
}

.google_search {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="nightsearch">
  <header>
    <div class="google_search">
      <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="nightsearchbox" placeholder="Search Google...">
      <button onclick="search()">
        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```